# Border radius in SVG d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have following svg:

```
    ` svg.append('g')
       .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M 0 150 L 0 0 L 190 0 L 190 150 Z")
        .attr("fill", "#f6f6f6"); `
```

Look like this:
[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't have much knowledge about svg curve. How can I set border radius like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done with Quadratic Bezier path:

```css
svg {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="180">
  <g transform="translate(10,10)">
    <path d="M 60,0 H 180 Q 190,0 190,10 V 140 Q 190,150 180,150 H 10 Q 0,150 0,140 V 60 Q 0,0 60,0 Z" fill="#d6d6d6"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have no idea what's going on here, Can you explain or give me some tutorial to understand about path. Because I also need svg like Top Right border, Bottom Left and Bottom Right border. I added images above. Thanks again.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman, just posted another answer about rounding corners. Take a look and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed description of path here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

The simplest way to round a corner is *Quadratic Bezier* path.
For example, if you need to round a top-right corner with approximate radius **r**, and the coordinate of the corner are **x** and **y**, The path will look like this:

1. Move to (**M**) / Line to (**L**) / Horizontal line (**H**) to **x - r**, **y**
2. Quadratic Bezier (**Q**) to **x**, **y + r**  via  **x**, **y**
3. Line to (**L**) / Vertical line (**V**) to the next point

For example, if the radius is 20 and the corner is in the point 100,100 the path will be **H 80,100 Q 100,100 100,120 V** ...

Comment: I studied and watched video from YouTube but I didn't solve it properly. But I need this badly. Will you do me a favor? Can you provide me other three svg please. I will be very thankful to you. Thank you.